# How to count total number of words and count characters of each word in a given string and create 1D array?

Tags: c

How to return the word count and character count into one array?

```
#define NUMBER_MOVIES 3
void getWordCount( char movies[NUMBER_MOVIES][40]);


int main ()
{

    char movies[NUMBER_MOVIES][40] = {"Jurasic World", "Captain America", "I spite on your grave"};

    getWordCount(movies);


    return 0;
}

void getWordCount(char movies[NUMBER_MOVIES][40])
{
    int i;
    int wordCount = 0;

    int wordCharCount[ ]; // need to store to this array

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(movies[i]); i++)
    {
        if (*movies[i] == ' ')
        {
            wordCount++;
            printf ("word count :%s, %d \n", movies[i], wordCount);
        }

        printf ("word count :%s, %d \n", movies[i], wordCount);
    }

}
```

I want to store all the word counts and character count into the same array which is wordCharCount []

Ex :Jurassic World ; array should be [2 8 5] . So 2 words and 1st word contains 8 characters & 2nd word contains 5 characters. Also array should be accessible from outside of the function.

Comment: There's no array to return in your code. And it doesn't work correctly. `movie name` returns 1 while `movie   name` returns 3

Comment: What do you mean by "return ... into an array" and "return to one array"?

Comment: Please include code that compiles and runs, including a main() function.  See [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/mcve)

Comment: I tried to clarify your code, but there are some problems that led to some serious guesswork. What is `movieNames` supposed to be? A `char**`?

Comment: You do realize that your Title contains 2 different problems, isn’t it?

Comment: Counts are integers; why do you need to return an array?  An array of what?  Your code does not seem to relate at all to your question or be at all a plausible attempt.  If you are truly lost with the code at least give an unambiguous statement of your requirements - describe the input and the desired output, with examples.  And your best attempt.  Your posted code tests only the first character of each `movieNames` string for a space - seems unlikely, that will just count the number of movies that start with a space.

Comment: @Michi : Worse than that, at least four requirements are specified: 1)Character count, 2)space count, 3)word count, 4)returning an array.

Comment: The edit helps, but it is not clear how you want to use the array for two different quantities - a struct array would make more sense.

Comment: @Clifford I just need to return all the word count, total charactor of one each word into one array from the movie array. Ex. [3 4 4 4 ] 3 words in the string each word has 4 charactors in it.

Comment: @techhelp : well if it is not clear (and it is not), you need to edit the question, not put the useful information in a comment.

Comment: @Clifford Oh :)) That's way too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious problem is your word count only has a single loop, but you need to scan every character in every movie - that suggests two *nested* loops.

Then the idea of returning two types of information in a single array is ill-advised - a structure would be more appropriate.  Then in C you cannot pass or return arrays by value, so it is usual to have the caller pass an array by reference for the function to place the results.

Consider:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct sMovie
{
    char title[40] ;
    int title_stats[40] ;
} ;

void getWordCount( struct sMovie* movies, int number_of_movies );

int main ()
{
    struct sMovie movies[] = { {"Jurassic World"}, 
                               {"Captain America"}, 
                               {"I spit on your grave"} } ;

    const int number_of_movies = sizeof(movies) / sizeof(*movies) ;
    getWordCount( movies, number_of_movies ) ;

    for( int m = 0; m < number_of_movies; m++ )
    {
        printf( "\"%s\" has %d words of lengths",
        movies[m].title,
        movies[m].title_stats[0] ) ;
        for( int w = 1; w <= movies[m].title_stats[0]; w++ )
        {
            printf( " %d", movies[m].title_stats[w] ) ;
        }
        printf( "\n" ) ;
    }

    return 0;
}

void getWordCount( struct sMovie* movies, int number_of_movies )
{
    // For each movie...
    for( int m = 0; m < number_of_movies; m++)
    {
        memset( movies[m].title_stats, 0, sizeof(movies[m].title_stats) ) ;
        movies[m].title_stats[0] = 1 ;

        // For each character
        for( int i = 0; movies[m].title[i] != 0; i++ )
        {
            int word = movies[m].title_stats[0] ; 
            movies[m].title_stats[word]++ ;

            if( movies[m].title[i] == ' ' )
            {
                movies[m].title_stats[word]-- ;
                movies[m].title_stats[0]++ ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
"Jurassic World" has 2 words of lengths 8 5                                                                                                              
"Captain America" has 2 words of lengths 7 7                                                                                                             
"I spit on your grave" has 5 words of lengths 1 4 2 4 5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how can I do the same thing without changing the main array [char movie]. I just want to do everything within the function and store all the results into 1D array (int array). Ex: [3 4 4 4] first element is word count. 2,3,4 element are the count of each word of the given string.

Comment: Having the array in the word count function serves no purpose - so you've counted the words, then what?  The purpose in storing them at all is to later process them.  I said "consider" because I an neither going to spoon-feed you or encourage you to bad design.  Your idea is flawed because, the word count is variable, and arrays are fixed, but you want a length for each word.  Either way your comment clarifies your requirements in a way your question does not - you should edit the question.

Comment: Ex : for Jurassic World ; array should be [2 8 5] . So 2 words and 1st word contains 8 characters & 2nd word contains 5 characters.

Comment: As I said, that is clear - but why could you not be that clear in the question?  I can only answer the question, not the comments.  Moreover there is probably enough in this answer for you to figure it out, for yourself.  If you get stuck, probably better to post a new question.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am a new guy here. I appreciate your help and editing on the question. I will be more careful when I post next problem.

Comment: Given the clarification to the question, I have updated the answer.  It is a poorer design, but what you asked for.  I would suggest that you have a separate structure member for the word count, so that the array holds only one type of information (character counts).

Comment: @Clifford Nice approach :)